# I am having a hard time understanding pseudo code

Tags: python, pseudocode

This is Pseudo Code to figure out the common greatest factor of 2 numbers.

get first number from user (use checkInt)
get second number from user (use checkInt)

determine which number is bigger
if second number is bigger swap number one and number two
for example:    if numberOne = 45  numberTwo = 55 then you need to swap so that
        numberOne = 55 and numberTwo = 45
if you really can’t figure that out look here

start while loop
numberThree equals numberOne mod numberTwo
if numberThree equals zero then 
end the loop and your GCF is numberTwo
else 
set NumberOne equal to numberTwo
set NumberTwo equal to numberThree
continue in loop

Here's some code that I solved from the pseudo code but I'[m having an hard time understanding the rest.

```
def gcd(m,n):
    if m<n: #assuming that m should always be greater than n
        (m,n) = (n,m)
```

Comment: [greatest common division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) this will help you

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? Stack Overflow is not really the place for personalized tutorials. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

idk if you can fix this but this is what i did for mine- theres just no user input or text

```
def gcf(n1,n2):

remainder = None

while remainder != 0:
    remainder = n1 % n2
    n1 = n2
    n2 = remainder

return n1
```